# PostPublish target didn't work on vs 2010

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I need to run a batch file after the publish done .. As I do the publish using publish item in the right click menu on my web project
then select the file system as publish type.

I put a target as below on the csproj file in order to execute a .bit file after the publish but it didn't work for me !

code I use in csproj like

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish"> 
   <Exec Command="echo %time%" />
</Target>
```

What I really want to do is to run bat file that will copy the *.pdb files from bin folder to a backup folder.
The issue is there's no action executed after the publish !
any help will be so appreciated .. :)